# Multi-dimensional PHP array index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
    Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
             [0] => 1
             [1] => 2
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
             [0] => 3
             [1] => 4
          )

      [2] => Array
          (
             [0] => 5
             [1] => 6
          )

      [3] => Array
          (
             [0] => 7
             [1] => 8
          )

    )
```

I want this array to be looks like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [0] => 1
           [1] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
           [0] => 3
           [1] => 7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
           [0] => 2
           [1] => 6
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
           [0] => 4
           [1] => 8
        )
)
```

I've spent almost 24 hours to accomplish this task. As you can understand, I need help. Please don't abuse on me by asking what have you tried. Can anyone accomplish this array job? thanks

---

Edit:

I have this array:

```
$yourArray = array(
    array(1,2),
    array(3,4),
    array(5,6),
    array(7,8),
);
```

It outputs this one:

```
Array
        (
          [0] => Array
              (
                 [0] => 1
                 [1] => 2
              )

          [1] => Array
              (
                 [0] => 3
                 [1] => 4
              )

          [2] => Array
              (
                 [0] => 5
                 [1] => 6
              )

          [3] => Array
              (
                 [0] => 7
                 [1] => 8
              )

        )
```

I want $yourArray to outputs this one:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
               [0] => 1
               [1] => 5
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
               [0] => 3
               [1] => 7
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
               [0] => 2
               [1] => 6
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
               [0] => 4
               [1] => 8
            )
    )
```

Let me write this too, I get output by using print_r($yourArray). And of course by using keyboard. Hope this helps

Comment: What exactly is the pattern you're going for? I mean, suppose the array had 100 elements - what would be the pattern then?

Comment: exactly what is the pattern for rearranging things? 1,3,2,4 and 5,7,6,8 make no logical sense

Comment: index 1 = index 0 + 4. Why? And without order ?

Comment: you really can not type the pattern with your hand? it only contains 8 numbers

Comment: we don't know what do you want, and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$array = array(
  array(1,2),
  array(3,4),
  array(5,6),
  array(7,8)
);

function processArray(&$array) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i][0] > 4) {
            $array[$i][0] = $array[$i][0] - 3;
        }
        if ($array[$i][1] < 5) {
            $array[$i][1] = $array[$i][1] + 3;
        }
    }
}

processArray($array);
print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 7 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 8 ) )
```

Comment: Finally, someone who understands php. thanks. that works like a charm. all I want was a simple for loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Considering what OP has made us understand, and *quite seriously*, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$yourArray = array(
    array(1,5),
    array(3,7),
    array(2,6),
    array(4,8),
);

var_dump($yourArray);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4f8e18773ef4db788df6aa1ab45c3c4c5dda47d).

I really can not understand whether it is serious or not.
Explain yourself.

Comment: I find your answer to be absolutely accurate (and hilarious), but I think you're feeding a troll here.

Comment: so you know how to echo with php.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the pattern so the only possibility I see is doing it *by hand*.

```
$foo = [
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [5,6],
    [7,8]
];

$bar = [
    [$foo[0][0],$foo[2][0]],
    [$foo[1][0],$foo[3][0]],
    [$foo[0][1],$foo[2][1]],
    [$foo[1][1],$foo[3][1]]
];

print_r($bar);
```

**Edit**
Use array() instead of [ ] if you're using an older version of PHP.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I don't see the pattern. If there's no pattern how would you write a loop that's sorting the data with a relative size? If you want to use it serveral times just put it in a function an return the new array. No need to use a loop in that case.

Comment: foreach($yourArray as $one){foreach($one as $two){echo $two; echo "--";} }

Comment: Do it yourself then if you can't provide any useful information and thinks a loop is something magical.